# How to programmatically mark files in dired based on file modification time?

Tags: dired

I'd like to write a bit of elisp to mark all files in a dired buffer that are "old": the files were last modified more than 10 days ago, say.

What would be a good way to do that? It seems there are functions to mark files in a dired buffer based on their name, using a regexp or whatever, but I don't see anything that handles file metadata other than the name.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't see anything that handles file metadata other than the name.

That's exactly the purpose of command **`dired-mark-sexp`**.  Use a Lisp sexp to match files, where the sexp can use (pseudo-)variables whose values are file metadata values.

You can use the command interactively or use it or some of its code from Lisp.

You can use (pseudo-)variable **`time`** in the sexp you use for marking -- compare some given time with the value of `time` for each file.

Here's the doc string. (This is the doc for the version from [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), which enhances the vanilla version in relatively minor ways -- you can use the vanilla version for what you want just as easily.)

> **`dired-mark-sexp`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> It is bound to `M-(`, `* (`, `menu-bar mark marks-mark marks-mark-sexp`.
>
> `(dired-mark-sexp PREDICATE &optional UNMARK-P)`
>
> Mark files for which PREDICATE returns non-`nil`.
>
> With a prefix arg, unmark or unflag those files instead.
>
> `PREDICATE` is a lisp sexp that can refer to the following symbols as
> variables:
>
> - `mode`   [string]  file permission bits, e.g. `"-rw-r--r--"`
> - `nlink`  [integer] number of links to file
> - `size`   [integer] file size in bytes
> - `uid`    [string]  owner
> - `gid`    [string]  group (If the `gid` is not displayed by `ls`,
>   this will still be set (to the same as `uid`))
> - `time`   [string]  the time that `ls` displays, e.g. `"Feb 12 14:17"`
> - `name`   [string]  the name of the file
> - `sym`    [string]  if file is a symbolic link, the linked-to name,
>   else `""`
> - `inode`  [integer] the inode of the file (only for `ls -i` output)
> - `blks`   [integer] the size of the file for `ls -s` output
>   (ususally in blocks or, with `-k`, in Kbytes)
>
> Examples:
>
> - Mark zero-length files: `(equal 0 size)'
> - Mark files last modified on Feb 2: `(string-match "Feb  2" time)'
> - Mark uncompiled Emacs Lisp files (`.el' file without a` .elc' file):
>
>   First, Dired just the source files: `dired *.el`.
>
>   Then, use `M-(` with this sexp:
>
>   ```
>     `(not (file-exists-p (concat name "c")))`
>   ```
>
> There's an ambiguity when a single integer not followed by a unit
> prefix precedes the file mode: It is then parsed as inode number
> and not as block size (this always works for GNU coreutils `ls`).
>
> Another limitation is that the `uid` field is needed for the
> function to work correctly.  In particular, the field is not
> present for some values of `ls-lisp-emulation`.
>
> This function operates only on the Dired buffer content.  It does not
> refer at all to the underlying file system.  Contrast this with
> `find-dired`, which might be preferable for the task at hand.

Comment: Oops, I misread `sexp` as `regexp` and didn't notice it -- thanks for pointing that out.

Still, the `time` variable is a little disappointing, since it's the displayed string; I was hoping for something structured -- either seconds since the epoch, or at least a consistently-formatted string. For the full general functionality I wanted, I'd need code that parses all those time strings into a better format. But there is a decent heuristic that I'll post as another answer.

Comment: Right, these pseudo-variables all involve text shown in the buffer. If you want a time object then you have to use Elisp functions to give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you use library[`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) then you can use command **`find-time-dired`**.  (You can also call it from Lisp or use part of its code, if you prefer.)

It puts only the selected files in a Dired buffer.  You can then mark them all (or some subset).

Here's the doc string:

> **`find-time-dired`** is an interactive Lisp function in [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el)().
>
> ```
> (find-time-dired DIR MIN-TIME MAX-TIME
>                  &optional DEPTH-LIMITS EXCLUDED-PATHS)
> ```
>
> **Find files in directory `DIR` newer or older than a timestamp**.
>
> The output is shown in a Dired buffer.
>
> - `MIN-TIME` is a `format-time` string parsable by `parse-time-string`, such
>   as `"2014-12-25 23:59:00"`.  Only files newer than this are shown.
>   If `MIN-TIME` is `nil` or a string matching regexp `"^\s-*$"`, there is
>   no lower time limit.
> - `MAX-TIME` is also a `format-time` string parsable by `parse-time-string`.  Only files older than this time are shown.  If `MAX-TIME` is `nil` or a string matching regexp `"^\s-*$"`, the upper
>   time limit is the current system time.
>
> Optional arg `DEPTH-LIMITS` is a list `(MIN-DEPTH MAX-DEPTH)` of the
> minimum and maximum depths.  If `nil`, search directory tree under `DIR`.
>
> Optional arg `EXCLUDED-PATHS` is a list of strings that match paths to
> exclude from the search.  If `nil`, search all directories.
>
> If args `DEPTH-LIMITS` and `EXCLUDED-PATHS` are both non-`nil` then the
> command run is essentially the following:
>
> ```
>  find . -mindepth MIN-DEPTH -maxdepth MAX-DEPTH
>      \( -path EXCLUDE1 -o -path EXCLUDE2 ... \)
>      -prune -o \( -TIME-SWITCH -SINCE-MIN -TIME-SWITCH +SINCE-MAX \)
>      LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `EXCLUDE1`, `EXCLUDE2`... are the `EXCLUDED-PATHS`, but shell-quoted.
> - `TIME-SWITCH` is `find-diredp-time-prefix' concatenated with` "min"`.
> - `SINCE-MIN` is the elapsed time since `MIN-TIME` in minutes.
> - `SINCE-MAX` is the elapsed time since `MAX-TIME` in minutes.
> - `LS-SWITCHES` is `(car find-ls-option)`.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of Drew's answer with the vanilla [`dired-mark-sexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/dired-x/Special-Marking-Function.html), something that works in full generality is pretty tricky, since the `time` variable is the formatted date/time string, and I'd need to parse all the different display formats into something structured: seconds since the epoch, or some other easily-parseable data structure.

There's probably a pretty good library or example code out there for that, but my use-case has a pretty simple heuristic that will work: look for times that don't have a colon in them.

The default `dired` / `ls` format appears to switch from showing the time to just showing a date for files that are six months old. That's good enough for me, so one answer to my question is: if your definition of "old" is "six months ago / whenever `ls` stops displaying times", then this will work:

Call `dired-mark-sexp` and for the predicate, use `(not (string-match-p ":" time)`.

Comment: Note that the various `find` options above are probably a better solution for the kind of interactive use I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, and probably the most direct and best answer to my specific question, is `find-dired`  with an argument of `-ctime +NDAYS`. Then in the resulting dired buffer, do `* t` to mark all the files (presuming you haven't marked any yet; `* t` toggles the marked state of all the files in the dired buffer.)

The only problem for me is that I'm using emacs on Windows and I'm not sure if I have a working version of `find`.